# How to set a client timeout for Redis Cloud db

Tags: redis

I'm using a redis stack database in my project, as part of the redis cloud free tier. I would like to set a 120s client timeout, so that any clients which are idle for a given amount of time are disconnected. How can I achieve this?

**What I've Tried** 
I have installed redis-cli for linux (on WSL2), and connected to my db with the command `redis-cli -u redis://[user]:[pass]@[host]:[port]`. Then I've tried:

- Running `CONFIG SET timeout 120` - this doesn't work as client timeout is an option set at runtime, but `CONFIG` is for in-flight config options.
- Running `FT.CONFIG SET timeout 120` - this returned error "Unknown command 'FT.CONFIG'".

Does anyone know how I can set my client timeout please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Redis team member helped me out in the Redis discord. Turns out, `FT.CONFIG` is disabled in cloud, and this cannot be modified for fixed (free 30MB) accounts. Therefore, it is **not possible** to set a client timeout when using Redis Cloud free tier.